# The Jquery code stop working when html elements removed and added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following jquery code that disables a button if none of the checkboxes is checked. Otherwise, the button is press-able.

Here are the jquery code:

```
$(function() {
 var checkboxes = $(':checkbox').click(function(event) {
 $('#group-edit-submit').prop("disabled", checkboxes.filter(':checked').length === 0);
 });
```

});

So it keep disabling #group-edit-submit button when none of the checkboxes is checked. The following is the button tag:

```
<div id="group-edit-submit-wrapper">
   <input disabled id="group-edit-submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit selected members" >
</div>
```

Here are the checkbox tags:

```
<div>
   <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
</div>
<div>
   </input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

In this scenario works fine. The button is initially disabled. When one of the checkboxes is clicked, the button is enabled.

However, when one of the checkboxes is removed by an activity so that the tags become:

```
<div>
   <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

In this case, the button is disabled permanently, even though the checkbox is checked, unless the page is releloaded. For some reason when there's a change in the tags, the script cannot detect the existing checkbox.

How can I fix the script without reloading the page? Is it possible? Any ideas?

### regards

Additional comment:

Hi all,
turns out that the checkbox selector is not detected when the whole div is replaced by jquery html function.

Consider the following HTML codes that I borrow from tbh:

```
<div id="group-edit-submit-wrapper">
  <input disabled id="group-edit-submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit selected members" >
</div>
<div id="some_container">
  <div>
    <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <div id="cbHolder">
    <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
  </div>
</div>
<input class="toggle" type="button" value="Toggle Checkbox">
```

Where the elements in questions are inside #some_container div. So, it has the following javascript that toggles the elements. When it hit, the whole #some_container will be replaced by jquery html() function:

```
$(function() {
   var checkboxes = $('input:checkbox').on('click',
     function(event) {
        $('#group-edit-submit').prop("disabled",checkboxes.filter(':checked').length === 0);
      });

     var toggle= true;
     $('.toggle').on('click',function(){
       toggle = !toggle;
       if(toggle){
         $('#some_container').html('<div><input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox"></div><div id="cbHolder"><input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox"></div>');
       }else {
         $('#cbHolder').remove();
     }
  });
});
```

The problem occurs consistently regardless how we write "disable checkbox" function. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: After OP's new comment, this change will fix it:

```
function SetupCheckboxClick() {
     $('input:checkbox').on('click', function(event) {
        $('#group-edit-submit').prop("disabled",$('input:checkbox').filter(':checked').length === 0);
      });
}
$(function() {
     SetupCheckboxClick();

     var toggle= true;
     $('.toggle').on('click',function(){
       toggle = !toggle;
       if(toggle){
         $('#some_container').html('<div><input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox"></div><div id="cbHolder"><input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox"></div>');
         SetupCheckboxClick();
       }else {
         $('#cbHolder').remove();
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: @ethereal1m I revised my answer for your new information.

Comment: Good job bro! this works perfectly. And very fast response too...  Could you explain it to me what is going on? why setupcheckboxclick must be called before and after html() call?

Comment: When you run the $("X").on("click", function(e) {}) code, it registers the function to the elements that satisfy the selector which currently exist. Once you replace the elements that you originally ran the on() function against, you have to run it again to register the function on the newly created checkbox elements.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/hisata/1/edit

Did this link not perform the way that you intended?

Changing the selector and using .on allows the

```
 var checkboxes = $('input:checkbox').on('click',
   function(event) {
 $('#group-edit-submit').prop("disabled",   checkboxes.filter(':checked').length === 0);
 });
```

**EDIT:**

```
 var checkboxes = $('#parentElement input:checkbox').on('click'...
```

Comment: Hello, I add another comment in replying your answer.

Comment: I think you can delegate events by adding the click event to the parent. 

http://jsbin.com/hisata/3/edit

You can read more about event delegation here: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/